# Why is comparison operator "==" returning "YES" even though the two vectors are different?

Tags: c++, stl

I tried running this code and the result shows "Yes" even thought the two vectors have different content and are of different sizes. I did not understand how the comparison operator works with vectors

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <int> example;  //First vector definition
    example.push_back(3);
    example.push_back(10);
    example.push_back(33);
    for(int x=0;x<example.size();x++)
    {
        cout<<example[x]<<" ";
    }
    if(!example.empty())
    {
        example.clear();
    }
    vector <int> another_vector; //Second vector definition
    another_vector.push_back(10);
    example.push_back(10);
    if(example==another_vector) //Comparison between the two vector
    {
        cout<<endl<<"YES";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<endl<<"NO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is "No"
But the output received is "Yes"

Comment: _the two vectors have different content and are of different sizes_ — that's not true.

Comment: what do you think are the contents of `example` when you call `==`, and why? Maybe thats the misunderstanding that needs an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Here, you are removing all elements from `example`:

```
if(!example.empty())
{
    example.clear();
}
```

The first vector is hence empty at this point. Then, you create `another_vector`, which is empty be default. Now,

```
another_vector.push_back(10);
example.push_back(10);
```

At this point, both vectors contain exactly one element: `10`. `operator ==` does what it's supposed to do then.